# Add identity to SSH every time I start the terminal

Tags: ssh

I need to put this in my ~/.bashrc

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/where_ever_privake_key_is
```

Where exactly in the file i should put these two lines?

Comment: It's always a good idea to put custom content in the bottom of the file.